# ASP.NET MVC + WebForms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I've been searching how to add webforms to MVC project but there lots of sites explaining only how to add MVC to an existing webforms project.

Is there a way to do that ? Maybe need to add some code at Web.Config ?
The .aspx.cs can't find any control on the .aspx webpage, that's the trouble !

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your reasoning behind wanting to do this?  The reason what you are finding is usually adding MVC to WebForms is because you're trying to ultimately move to ASP.NET MVC?  Not the other way around.

Comment: I did that because I have a framework in Webforms and to speed up my web development, I had to use it on my MVC. Well, I moved the folder to my project, so I guess that was the reason my .aspx.cs wasn't finding my controls .. I copy+paste code, now It's working ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a WebForm to your MVC project and have it work.  You can also add WebForm controls to an MVC view as long as you have a `<form runat="server">` around it.

Comment: As jamesaharvey said I'd like to know the reason.  Can you explain why you want to do this?  There's most likely a better way.

Answer (score 1):

It irks me to post this ... but I went Add New Item ... and added an Ajax Web Form into an MVC 2 project and the code behind was added and linked to the web form.